# libusb node usb get device instance path

Tags: node.js, usb, libusb, device-manager

Using Device Manager in windows on a USB device I get this in the device instance path property:

```
USB\VID_0403&PID_E868\02302692
```

I'm trying to get this info from the Node USB library which is based on libusb. When I query I get these values:

```
idVendor: 1027,
idProduct: 59496,
bcdDevice: 1536,
iSerialNumber: 3,
```

Which when converted are those values in the device manager.

//E868 = 59496

//1027 = 403

//1536 = 600

HOWEVER, I can't seem to find the \02302692. When I run lsusb -v that value is also not there.

Where is Windows getting the \02302692. If using libusb what is the property that retrieves that value? I thought it was the iSerialNumber??

To get what I have I'm calling

```
var lxdevice = usb.findByIds(1027, 59496);
console.log(lxdevice.deviceDescriptor);
```

in the node usb library. https://github.com/tessel/node-usb

Comment: Device serial number i.e. the string descriptor pointed to by iSerialNumber (if nonzero). You need to fetch it using that index (presumably using `getStringDescriptor`).

Comment: @Hasturkun Yes, that worked: getStringDescriptor(lxdevice.deviceDescriptor.iSerialNumber, function callback(error, data){